# Межязыковое взаимодействие

Tags: java, c++, python, service

Имеется несколько программ, написанных на разных языках (питон, Ява, плюса).
Требуется из одной программы (написанной на яве) последовательно передавать данные, ожидать их обработки и получать ответ. Как реализовать интерфейс межязыкового взаимодействия? Есть ли готовые решения? По каким словам гуглить?

Answer (score 3):

Слишком общий вопрос на который нельзя дать однозначный вопрос.
Из вариантов:

- REST API
- Брокеры сообщений (RabbitMQ, 0MQ)
- unix piplines
- RPC, в т.ч. с использованием готовых реализаций, например Thrift
- общение через сокеты

Answer (score -1):

Привет!
Правильно ли я понимаю, что тебе нужно "увязать" между собой реализованные программы? Если так, то тебе не важно на каком языке они описаны. Продумай просто формат данных и схему обмена.
Пример:
Программа на яве принимает в качестве входных параметров два числа, складывает их и сохраняет в некотором файле их сумму.
Алгоритм использования этой программы из другой был бы такой:
вызвать первую программу, передать на вход 2 числа. В указанном месте ожидать появление файла. Когда файл появился - прочитать из него результат, выполнить какие-то действия...

Comment: ...а вторая программа прочитает файл так быстро, что он окажется пустым, так как первая программа ещё не успела вписать в свежесозданный файл число. Не надо так.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Не хватает признака завершения работы первой программы.